# MySQL get midnight data for different timezone

Tags: mysql, timezone

I have a table which stores information every hour with table columns

```
id - PK
value - FLOAT
createdAt - TIMESTAMP
```

The `createdAt` field stores data in GMT timezone every hour. For example: `2020-12-14 00:00:00`, `2020-12-14 01:00:00`, etc.

I want to query data in this table based on the timezone. So if I want values at midnight of 2020-12-14 but with CET Timezone. How do I query that?

Comment: Use CONVERT_TZ() function. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz

Comment: The data is stored every 30 mins, I need the data for every hour, without the 30 mins being included.

Comment: Show some sample data (3-5 rows) and desired output for it.